# Add url parameter without redirctAttributes

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I understand that I can use redirectAttributes to add url parameters, 
but some actions return views and then the set attributes won't be in url because there is no redirct.

How can I add extra url parameters to an action ?

**Example:**

I request **/users/1**

Some action in my controller will respond with a view called show.html

Now I'd like to add **/users/1?include-posts=true**

```
    // pseudo code; get user
    @RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
    public String show(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        User user = repository.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        // the url will be /users/1
        // now do something to add ?include-posts=true
        // I can't use redirect here
        return "show";
    }
```

Comment: Do you want something like this `return "redirect:/users/1?include-posts=true";` ?Could you clarify more.

Comment: @SanjayRawat, No I don't want to use redirect, I'm returning a view but I want to add additional url parameters. I'm getting users/1 as the request.

Comment: So you want to hit `/users/1` then `@Controller` to return `show.html` view and then you want your url to be `/users/1?include-posts=true`. Is that correct? And if yes, why do you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SanjayRawat, You are right now, the example above is just pseudo code to make it simple, What I'm trying to achieve is, I want to add the url parameter page=n depending on the size of the arraylist, if the list is just 10 in size there is no need to add page=n, if the size is >10, I have to add page=1 to the url. So basically I can't add the parameters in a form because I don't know the size yet, just after I've counted the size, I'm able to set additional parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what would you achieve by setting param in url after returning view from Controller. If you do that then that url param would mean nothing but just a marker to the User that the Array has more than 10 items and this is page-1 of that. But I suppose you want to hit `/users/1` get arraylist items and show only 10 items in the view and set url param as `page=1`. If yes then I assume you'd have a `@RequestMapping("/users/1")` with `RequestParam` as `page` and return items for that page.